# highlight in comment

Tags: support

Sometimes you can highlight a user (@Robuuust) for example in a comment. But there are also times when I try this and I end up with no option. It will be removed when I enter someone's name.

What's going wrong here? What do I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ is used to ping a user, and at a time you can ping only one user.

Comment: @Robuust It is removed when referring to post author since he/she get notified anyway, unless there are comments from other users in place. (It's all explained in the linked dupe)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not find that dupe.

Comment: Yeah, the right term is "comment reply" not "highlight a user", without knowing correct term it's hard to find proper information.